# Reading integers from a text file and putting them into objects to store into a hashmap

Tags: java, object, integer

For an assignment, I am supposed to read a text file that holds 545 sets of integers, each set holds 8 integers which I am trying to store into an object "wayPoint" with 8 variables for each of the integers.

I'm trying to output my results to verify that I have indeed loaded the integers into the object but the console outputs nothing.

My classes are very rough, sorry for the lack of prose.

This is the class for the waypoint:

```
public class Test {


   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       System.out.println ();
   }


   public void readwayPoints()
   {
       Scanner readFile = null;
       try
       {
           readFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(
           "insert text file here"));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
       {
           System.out.println("File not found.");
           System.exit(0);
       }

       int x = 0, y= 0, height = 0, cost = 0, gold = 0, mapX = 0, mapY = 0, neighbor = 0;
       int count = 0;

       List<Waypoint> list = new ArrayList<>();
       while (readFile.hasNextLine()) 
       {

            x = readFile.nextInt();
            y = readFile.nextInt();
            height = readFile.nextInt();
            cost = readFile.nextInt();
            gold = readFile.nextInt();
            mapX = readFile.nextInt();
            mapY = readFile.nextInt();
            neighbor = readFile.nextInt();
            Waypoint wayP = new Waypoint(x, y, height, cost, gold, mapX, mapY, neighbor);
            System.out.println(wayP);
            list.add(wayP);
        }


   }
```

Here is the Waypoint class:

```
   public class Waypoint
   {
       private int x, y, height, cost, gold, mapX, mapY, neighbor;

       public Waypoint (int x, int y, int height, int cost, int gold, int mapX, int mapY,
                    int neighbor)
       {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this. height = height;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.gold = gold;
            this.mapX = mapX;
            this.mapY = mapY;
            this.neighbor = neighbor;
       }

       public String toString()
       {
            return "x:" + this.x + "y:" + this.y + "height:" + this.height + "cost" + this.cost
                            + "gold:" + this.gold + "mapX:" + this.mapX + "mapY:" + this.mapY + "neighbor"
                            + this.neighbor;
       }

   }
```

}

An example of the text file:

```
 20 120 102  84   0   0   0 0
 20 260  85  75   0   0   0 0
 20 360  91  74   0   0   0 0
 40 220 111  73   0   0   0 0
 40 280  77  94   0   0   0 0
 40 300  68  67   0   0   0 0
 60 480 135  96   0   0   0 0
 80 400 149  92   0   0   0 0
100 160 122  74   0   0   0 0
100 240 104  70   0   0   0 0
100 460 120  54   0   0   0 0
120 460 131  98   0   0   0 0
140 160 117  80   0   0   0 0
140 280  78  76   0   0   0 0
140 420 135  76   0   0   0 0
160 320 163  58   0   0   0 0
180 240 134  92   0   0   0 0
```

Comment: are you looping over the result and calling toString() on each waypoint? Also java classes usually begin with upper case

Answer (score 2):

Well you dont store it anyhwere, you dont even creating a wayPoint instance.

This should do the trick :

```
    List<wayPoint> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {           
        x = readFile.nextInt();
        y = readFile.nextInt();
        height = readFile.nextInt();
        cost = readFile.nextInt();
        gold = readFile.nextInt();
        mapX = readFile.nextInt();
        mapY = readFile.nextInt();
        neighbor = readFile.nextInt();
        wayP = new wayPoint(x, y, height, cost, gold, mapX, mapY, neighbor);
        System.out.println(wayP);
        list.add(wayP);
    }
```

By the way, rename your class wayPoint to WayPoint, it is almost a "law" in Java.

Comment: I've adjusted the code in my main post to reflect the feedback in the thread and still am having difficulty seeing any output in the console. I appreciate the help so far! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, remember to mark this message as accepted :). If you dont see any output, the problem is probably somewhere else (it maybe doesnt even run this part of code, or your output is set to somewhere else)